# Error using ^ One argument must be a square matrix and the other must be a scalar. Use POWER (.^) for elementwise power

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, minimization, simulated-annealing

I'm Trying to write minimization function from this function,

```
(4-2.1*x1^2+x1^4/3)*x1^2+x1*x2+(-4+4*x2^2)*x2^2
```

where,
   -10 <= x1 <= 10 and -10 <= x2 <= 10.

this what I'm writing, is this right?

```
min = -10;
max = 10;
x1 = min+max*rand();
x2 = min+max*rand();
T = 1.0;
Tmin = 0.0000001;
refresh = 0.9;
finalMin = (4-2.1*x1^2+x1^4/3)*x1^2+x1*x2+(-4+4*x2^2)*x2^2;
finalCoordinate=[x1,x2];
while(T>Tmin)
    i=0;
    while(i<=300)
        x1= min+max*rand(1,1);
        x2= min+max*rand(1,1);
        newMin = (4-2.1*x1^2+x1^4/3)*x1^2+x1*x2+(-4+4*x2^2)*x2^2;
        delta1 = finalMin-newMin;
        if(newMin < finalMin)
            finalMin=newMin;
            finalCoordinate=[x1,x2];
        elseif(2.71828^(delta/T))>(0+(rand(1)*1))
            finalCoordinate=[x1,x2];
        end;
        i=i+1;
    end;
    T = T*refresh;
end;
```

But why, at

```
elseif(2.71828^(delta/T))>(0+(rand(1)*1))




Error using ^ One argument must be a square matrix and the other must be a scalar. Use POWER (.^) for elementwise power.
```

And how to obtain 100% accuracy from that coordinate?

Comment: As far as I can see, you don't actually define `delta` anywhere. You do define the similarly named `delta1`

Comment: Don't use HTML snippets for stuff that's not HTML. All that does is generate all kinds of buttons and other pointless screen filling that doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the error message, `delta` is probably no scalar. You didn't define it in your code here.

In general, your problem is a *nonlinear constrained optimization problem* which can be quickly solved with `fmincon` from the Optimization Toolbox:

```
fun = @(x) (4-2.1*x(1)^2+x(1)^4/3)*x(1)^2+x(1)*x(2)+(-4+4*x(2)^2)*x(2)^2;
x0 = rand(2,1)*20-10;
[x,fval] = fmincon(fun, x0, [],[], [],[], [-10;-10], [10;10])
```